# Does the (Small) Ring of Glow prevent me from catching Night Fish?

Tags: stardew-valley

Somebody in the  game noted that night fish do not like the light. Obviously this is related to them being night fish. But is it also a hint that hen fishing I should unequip me ring of glow since obviously it is also a source of light?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it does not! I have caught all the night fishes with my Ring of Glow equipped.

Answer (score 1):

No, glow rings have no effect on what fish you can catch, only time of day, weather, season and location.

Comment: Are you able to provide a source for this? Even if it is just from your own in game experience you should state that is the case.